# How to save two databases records in same Hibernate Transaction?

Tags: mysql, database, hibernate, session, transactions

I want to save the records in two databases 
in case any exception is thrown by the transaction
both database `Transaction` should get `reverted`
How can I implement in my code?

Here is my sample code

```
public void save(Vendor vendor, Ledger ledger) throws Exception 
{
    Transaction primaryTx = null, secondaryTx = null;
    Session primarySession = null, secondarySession = null;
    try 
    {
        secondarySession = HibernateUtil.getSession("secondarydb");
        secondaryTx = secondarySession.beginTransaction();
        secondarySession.save(ledger);
        vendor.setLedgerId(ledger.getId());

        primarySession = HibernateUtil.getSession("primarydb");
        primaryTx = primarySession.beginTransaction();
        primarySession.saveOrUpdate(vendor);
        secondaryTx.commit();
        primaryTx.commit();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        if (secondaryTx != null) 
        {
            secondaryTx.rollback();
        }
        if (primaryTx != null) 
        {
            primaryTx.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if (secondarySession != null && secondarySession.isOpen()) 
        {
            secondarySession.close();
        }
        if (primarySession != null && primarySession.isOpen()) 
        {
            primarySession.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Actually in my above code

1. First I'm doing secondary session Transaction `secondaryTx.commit();`
2. Then I'm doing primary session Transaction `primaryTx .commit();`
3. In case if I get any exception in Primary Transaction `rollBack` should be done
4. But `Secondary Transaction` data not get `Reverted` and `Primary Transaction` successfully Reverted
5. **How can I revert both Transactions Data?**

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void save(Vendor vendor, Ledger ledger) throws Exception {
    Transaction primaryTx = null, secondaryTx = null;
    Session primarySession = null, secondarySession = null;
    try {
        secondarySession = HibernateUtil.getSession("secondarydb");
        secondaryTx = secondarySession.beginTransaction();
        secondarySession.save(ledger);
        vendor.setLedgerId(ledger.getId());

        primarySession = HibernateUtil.getSession("primarydb");
        primaryTx = primarySession.beginTransaction();
        primarySession.saveOrUpdate(vendor);
        secondarySession.flush(); // add this line
        primarySession.flush(); // add these line
        secondaryTx.commit();
        primaryTx.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (secondaryTx != null) {
            secondaryTx.rollback();
        }
        if (primaryTx != null) {
            primaryTx.rollback();
        }
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (secondarySession != null && secondarySession.isOpen()) {
            secondarySession.close();
        }
        if (primarySession != null && primarySession.isOpen()) {
            primarySession.close();
        }
    }
}
```

1. Flush before commit.It will throw exception.So you can rollback successfully.